# Parsing Log file in Python and saving it to csv

Tags: python

I have a log file which is around 1.5 GB.
The file contains log data in the following format:

```
A|B|C|D delimited by '|' character and does not have column names. It has only 
four columns
```

How can I parse it to python 3.6 and then export it to .csv  file and add user defined column names.
How delimit the number of rows while exporting to .csv file.

I have started writing the code as below but do not know how to proceed further:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

infile = r"D:\Sys\file.log"

df = pd.DataFrame()
with open(infile,encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
   f = f.readlines()

for line in f:
   print(line)
```

I am able to get the lines as I checked it with print statement.

Comment: Can those columns* also possibly have '|' in them? If not you can just split on that delimiter.

Comment: No rows will not have "|" delimiter. How to use delimiter and store in CSV

Comment: Okay, and what do you wish to do with pandas?

Comment: I think I have clearly mentioned in the question above. Please read my question above.

Comment: Well, you don't need pandas to do it, that's why I asked. Is a solution without pandas okay?

Comment: Yeah anything would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that does not involve pandas:

```
import csv

with open(r"D:\Sys\file.log", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f, open('logfile.csv', 'w') as f2: # or 'wb' if on python2
    writer = csv.writer(f2)
    writer.writerow(['Index', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) # replace with your custom column header

    i = 0
    for line in f:
        writer.writerow([i] + line.rstrip().split('|'))
        i += 1
        if i == 10000:
            break
```

Use `csv.writer` to write data to a file in csv format.

Comment: io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: @Olay: Sorry, try again. There were a couple of issues before.

Comment: Can I delimit the number of rows like 10000 because if I append all rows the csv file will be huge.

Comment: You mean, number the rows with an index or limit the number to 10000? I've edited my answer to show you how to do both.

Comment: I meant can we give range in "open"  like (1 to 300) or (200 to 500)

Comment: Sure. If your lower = 200 and upper = 500...`if i < lower: continue; elif lower <= i <= upper: write your line; else: break`

Comment: However you can't open randomly read lines _unless you know how big each line is_. In that case you can use `f.seek(n)` where n is the number of bytes to skip.

Comment: Let me try.. I will get back to you in 10 minutes. Code is running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147938/discussion-between-olay-and-coldspeed).

Answer (score 1):

As your log has a good format,you can use `csv.reader` to read it.And then rewrite it.You can write it using `csv.writer`.

```
import csv
with open('csv.log', 'r') as logfile, open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(logfile, delimiter='|')
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|',)
    writer.writerow(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'])
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Refference:
[Reader Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#reader-objects)
[Writer Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects)

Comment: The word `spam` and `eggs` in code can only mean it came from the official docs. Nothing wrong with that... just saying.

Comment: Yes, I just read the official docs,and found this works.I will add the url of official docs to the answer.

Comment: @Coldspeed thank you , I changed the words to make it look better.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas, you could achieve what you want with the following code :

```
import pandas
chunk_size = 10000
custom_headers = ["custheader-1", "custheader-2", "custheader-3", "custheader-4"]
reader = pandas.read_table("log.txt", sep="|", header=None, chunksize=chunk_size)
for index, chunk in enumerate(reader):
    if (index == 0):
        chunk.to_csv("out.csv", index=False, sep="|", header=custom_headers)
    else:
        chunk.to_csv("out.csv", index=False, mode='a', sep="|", header=False)
```